# How to use Extended Event in Azure SQL Database

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, ssms

I was working with SQL Server database before and now move to Azure SQL database.
SQL Profiler in SSMS in preety tool to capture query performance and raw query generated from Entityframework which help to find out some issue in our application.

But Azure SQL Database does not have SQL Profiling feature so i am thinking to use Extended Event session for query tracking in SSMS. But "Watch Live Data" button while right click in session is always grey out and disabled in Azure SQL Database and i found that feature not available in SQl Database. So how can I track query like in SQL Profiler while using Extended Event Session in Azure SQL Database ?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Profiler is being deprecated starting with SQL Server 2016. You can enable the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) though. The Query Store lets you look at the last queries that were executed against a given database. The query texts are stored in the view `sys.query_store_query_text` and the execution plans are stored in `sys.query_store_plan`. From the execution plan, you can troubleshoot any performance issue.

In the case of query performance, Azure SQL Database offers a few graphical tools that may be of interest: Performance Overview, [Performance Recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-advisor-portal), [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance), [Automatic Tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning). These tools are available through the Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks Estienne-granet for the reply. Actually what i need is to watch raw SQL generated by EntityFramwork like in SQl Profiler. Is there any visual tool for this ?

Comment: This may be possible using the Query Store (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store). Please let us how it goes.